# Python Class with sub properties (Beginner)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I am looking for a way to have a class with sub properties in it, so that I can group common properties together and have references to the main class. Example:

```
class RoadNetwork(object): # This is the main class
    def __init__(self):
        self.Types = ['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']

    class HighWay(self): # This is the subclass
        def __init__(self):
            MaxSpeed = 55
            MinSpeed = 35
            Type = self.Types[2]


>>> roads = RoadNetwork()
>>> roads.Types
['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']
>>> roads.HighWay.MaxSpeed
55
>>> roads.HighWay.MinSpeed
35
>>> roads.HighWay.Type
'Pavement'
>>>
```

Comment: Keep reading. The concept you're after is 'composition'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think inheritance is what you are looking for, since a HighWay is a type of road but it is not a type of RoadNetwork.  As far as I understand it, you just want a single instance of `RoadNetwork` and your types of roads would all have a reference to the same `RoadNetwork` instance.

I would also suggest moving some of your instance variables into class attributes.  For example all instances of `HighWay` will have the same `roadType` so instead of assigning this at the instance level they would share the class value.

The simplest way to do this would probably be to just have all of your road types reference the global variable `roads`, but using global variables in this way is generally looked down upon.  A better solution would be to use a class factory where you pass the reference to your `RoadNetwork` instance:

```
def highway_factory(roads):
    class HighWay(object):
        max_speed = 55
        min_speed = 35
        road_type = roads.types[2]
    return HighWay

class RoadNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']
        self.HighWay = highway_factory(self)
```

Example:

```
>>> roads = RoadNetwork()
>>> roads.types
['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']
>>> roads.HighWay.max_speed
55
>>> roads.HighWay.min_speed
35
>>> roads.HighWay.road_type
'Pavement'
```

Comment: This is exacly it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You got inheritance wrong. This is how you should declare a class hierarchy:

```
class RoadNetwork(object):  # This is the main class
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']

class HighWay(RoadNetwork): # This is the subclass
    def __init__(self):
        RoadNetwork.__init__(self)
        self.maxSpeed = 55
        self.minSpeed = 35
        self.roadType = self.types[2]
```

For example:

```
road = RoadNetwork()
road.types
=> ['Dirt', 'Gravel', 'Pavement']

highway = HighWay()
highway.maxSpeed
=> 55
highway.minSpeed
=> 35
highway.roadType
=> 'Pavement'
```

Comment: There is no way to prevent creating an 2nd object with HighWay class and call the HighWay properties through the road class?

Comment: @orange I think you're confusing two different concepts: inheritance and composition. One option is to do as I did in my answer, create a class hierarchy and put the "common" attributes in the superclass. Another option would be to have a separate HigWay object and declare an attribute of type HighWay in the class RoadNetwork - but you won't declare HighWay _inside_ RoadNetwork, nor will HighWay extend RoadNetwork

Comment: @orange Now, answering your comment: You don't _have to_ create a RoadNetwork object, just instantiate a HighWay object and it'll have access to its superclass' attributes: HighWay will have access to the attributes of both classes - that is, we can call road's properties through the highway, not the other way around